# How to modify/update an array in numpy without changing original

Tags: numpy

Is there a Numpy operation that does this?

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.some_update_method(a, 0, 99) # b is array([99, 2, 3]), a is unchanged.
```

In J this is called "amend", but I don't know what it might be called in Numpy (if it exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a copy of the original array and then modify it in place:

```
b = a.copy()
b[0] = 99

b
# [99  2  3]

a
# [1 2 3]
```

Comment: Disappointed that Numpy doesn't have a functional amend, but I can wrap this in a function so it will solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Import `copy` and use `deepcopy`.

```py
import copy

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = copy.deepcopy(a)

#modify b
```

You can use just `copy` to keep the original the same (the copied elements will be referenced and dependent from the original list), `deepcopy` will keep each object completely independent, but use twice the memory and whatever time it takes to reproduce the object.

Comment: `deepcopy` is needed only if the array is `object` dtype.  For regular numeric dtype it doesn't do anything more than the `copy` method.   `object `dtype array are like lists, containing references.

Comment: Good to know about when to use deepcopy.